# C# COM DLL with gcServer = true and gcAllowVeryLargeObjects = true

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, garbage-collection, com-interop

Let’s assume I've

> - a C# DLL called `managed.dll` which is COM visible.
> - a C# EXE called `magaged.exe` which uses the `managed.dll` and which has an app.config called `managed.exe.config`.
> - a C++ EXE called `unmanaged.exe` which calls the `managed.dll` over COM and which has the same app.config as the C# EXE but called `unmanaged.exe.config` in this case.

The `managed.dll` has the following two test properties:

```
public bool IsServerGC
{
    get { return System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC; }
}

public bool AreVeryLargeObjectsAllowed
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            long l = 20000;
            double[,] d = new double[l, l];
            return l * l == d.LongLength;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
}
```

The `app.config` looks like that for both EXEs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    <!--<gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>-->
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

For the `managed.exe` everything works as expected. But for the `unmanaged.exe` the `<gcServer enabled="true"/>` setting is ignored. I cannot understand why?

I can see that the `unmanaged.exe.config` is loaded when the first instance of a COM object is created. It's as well used, tested by changing for example the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` setting.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Windows 7 (64-bit) and .NET 4.6.1. Everything is compiled for x64.

Any ideas why the `<gcServer enabled="true"/>` setting is ignored when the `managed.dll` is used over COM?

Regards
Wollmich

Comment: The obscure factoid is that a [ComVisible] server *still* uses a .config file.  But it has to be named client.exe.config and copied into the same directory as the client.exe.  Fairly unpleasant since you don't always control the client app, but serviceable and a wholeheckofalot easier than writing your own CLR host so you can configure the CLR before it starts executing code.

Comment: @HansPassant, does the client.exe.config file get loaded even if the client.exe is not a managed exe? does it get loaded as soon as a managed dll is loaded in the process?

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried that. But it seems not working. Inside my C# DLL there is a method which calls System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC to check the garbage collection mode.
Managed.exe and Managed.exe.config is working.
Unmanaged.exe and Unmanaged.exe.config is not working.

Comment: Yes, it works fine if the client.exe is not managed.  They rarely are.  "Doesn't work" doesn't help me help you.  The name and location matter.  And you can't get large objects when the host app runs in 32-bit mode.  SysInternals' Process Monitor might get you somewhere, assuming it still works correctly on your machine, you should see the CLR searching for the .config file.

Comment: @HansPassant: I used now the SysInternals Process Monitor and I can see the Unmanaged.exe.config is loaded just before the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config. And my unmanaged runs in 64-bit mode. But the method which calls System.Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC inside my C# DLL still return false. My config file looks like that:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
Any other ideas?

Comment: @HansPassant: In the mean time I found out that the Unmanaged.exe.config file is loaded and used. I can see that the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects setting is working but not the gcServer setting. In the Managed.exe both settings are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find two different workarounds:

**Workaround 1** (Host CLR before COM Interop)

I had to change the following things:

> - the C++ EXE called `unmanaged.exe` has to host the CLR first and set the startup flags before calling the `managed.dll` over COM.

The source file of the `unmanaged.exe` looks like that:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <metahost.h>
#include <mscoree.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")
#import "..\managed\bin\Release\managed.tlb"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Init .NET
    ICLRMetaHost    *pMetaHost = nullptr;
    ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, (LPVOID*)&pMetaHost);
    hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
    hr = pRuntimeInfo->SetDefaultStartupFlags(STARTUP_SERVER_GC, NULL);
    // Init COM
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    IManagedTestClassPtr pManagedTestClass(__uuidof(ManagedTestClass));
    // and so on ...

    // End COM
    CoUninitialize();
    // END .NET
    if (pMetaHost)
    {
        pMetaHost->Release();
        pMetaHost = NULL;
    }
    if (pRuntimeInfo)
    {
        pRuntimeInfo->Release();
        pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my personal preferred workaround, because no additional helper.dll is needed.

**Workaround 2** (Use C++/CLI DLL before COM Interop)

I had to change the following things:

> - add a C++/CLI DLL called `helper.dll` which has an app.config called `helper.dll.config`. The app.config is the same as for the C++ EXE.
> - the C++ EXE called `unmanaged.exe` has to call first a function from the C++/CLI `helper.dll` before calling the `managed.dll` over COM.

The `helper.dll` has the following header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifdef TEST_HELPER_EXPORTS
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
#pragma comment (lib, "..\\x64\\Release\\helper.lib") // if importing, link also
#endif
DLLAPI int IsServerGC();
```

and the following source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define TEST_HELPER_EXPORTS
#include "helper.h"
int IsServerGC()
{
    return System::Runtime::GCSettings::IsServerGC ? 1 : 0;
}
```

The source file of the `unmanaged.exe` looks like that:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\helper\helper.h"
#import "..\managed\bin\Release\managed.tlb"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int isServerGC = IsServerGC(); // Init .NET with the C++/CLI helper.dll
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); // Init COM
    IManagedTestClassPtr pManagedTestClass(__uuidof(ManagedTestClass));
    // and so on ...
}
```

If the `helper.dll.config` file is missing the `<gcServer enabled="true"/>` setting is ignored again. The other settings, for example the  `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` setting, are defined in the   `unmanaged.exe.config` file.

For me it's still not clear why the `<gcServer enabled="true"/>` setting is ignored when I'm not using the CLR hosting or the workaround `helper.dll` first?

Regards
Wollmich

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug and was likely introduced in .NET Framework 4.0. While we can’t commit to a timeline, we’re planning on fixing this in an upcoming release of .NET Framework.

Meanwhile, you can work this around by setting the following environment variable:

```
COMPlus_BuildFlavor=SVR
```

Please note that all the `COMPlus_*` environment variables are unsupported and only meant for debugging/developing the CLR itself. So please keep this in mind and make a decision that makes sense for your environment.