# gcServer setting not being passed from unmanaged exe to managed dll

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, app-config, unmanaged

I have a .net library (framework v4.6.1) called by unmanaged code, and would like to configure its garbage collection.  I've tried using the app.exe.config below, but GCSettings.IsServerGC returns false so it isn't working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Running procmon, I can verify that this is indeed the file gets opened and read.  What could be going wrong?  I've tried setting the COMPlus_gcServer environment variable to 1 and that fails to enable server mode as well.

Comment: How do you host it if it's called by unmanaged code? Those settings are read by the default .NET host (`exe` file), your host probably ignores it.

Comment: @KonradKokosa: Oh yes, there is a managed C++/CLI project in the middle.

Comment: Right, so there is a place to configure it with CLR Hosting API.

Comment: That sounds like a really good clue, albeit one that I don't understand yet, as I only wrote the managed layer.  I will look into it but if you could expand a little that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this unmanaged.exe.config setting gets fumbled by .Net 4.x, but it can be picked up in managed.dll.config instead if the managed dll is told to make a CLR call soon enough after application startup.  Details of this workaround can be found here:

[C# COM DLL with gcServer = true and gcAllowVeryLargeObjects = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200195/c-sharp-com-dll-with-gcserver-true-and-gcallowverylargeobjects-true)